# is their any api to get notification on the depricated api's in google app script platform?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to check for depricated api list in GAS so that I can modify the code well in advance.
**so is their any api to get list of the depricated api ?**

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs for this that I am aware of, but Google posts a sunset schedule for all GAS related APIs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset). Hope this helps!